# What should be the value of [1,2,3].slice(1,undefined)?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome

I found a difference in the handling of

```
[1,2,3].slice(1, undefined)
```

between chrome (that returns `[2,3]`) and firefox (that returns `[]`).

Both of course instead agree on `[2, 3]` as the value of

```
[1,2,3].slice(1)
```

and they also both agree on `[]` as the value of

```
[1,2,3].slice(1, null)
```

Which of the two is correct? Or may be this not clearly specified in the standard?

Comment: What version of Firefox? I don't get that result in FF5 when using `undefined`. The result from `null` is expected since it will be converted to `0`.

Comment: Are you not going to share what version of FF you were using? It would be interesting to know if this issue still existed in FF4.

Comment: @Patrick: The problem is present in firefox 3.6.18 on ubuntu 10.10.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The specification says:](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.4.4.10)

> 7. If *end* is **undefined**, let *relativeEnd* be *len*; else let *relativeEnd* be ToInteger(*end*).

Which Firefox version are you using? Firefox 5 gives me correctly `[2, 3]`. *Update:* Firefox 3.6 returns indeed an empty array.

I don't know what is wrong here, because if you call `slice()` without a second parameter, `end` will be `undefined` too.

<s>**Update:**</s>

After playing around a bit, it seems that an empty array is returned if the second parameter passed to `.slice()` is `NaN`. Example (`+undefined` returns NaN):

```
> [1,2,3].slice(1, +undefined)
> []
```

This is the same in Firefox and in Chrome.

Unfortunately, this is also not conform to the specification, as [`ToInteger(NaN)` *<sup>[spec]</sup>*](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_9.4) should return `0`, so the the array should actually be sliced to the end.

I don't claim that this is the reason why it does not work properly in some Firefox versions, I don't know the implementation.

*Incident of minor disorientation... never mind.*

Comment: They were probably checking how many arguments there were instead of checking for `undefined`, which is why it worked if you called it without a second parameter.

Comment: @Matthew: Probably, but this is not the only reason. It also seems they did not use `ToIngeger`, as `ToInteger(undefined)` should give `0` (which would be ok). Maybe they used `ToNumber()`, which, passing `undefined`, gives `NaN`. And this returns indeed an empty array.

Comment: *"Unfortunately, this is also not conform to the specification, as ToInteger(NaN) [spec] should return 0, so the the array should actually be sliced to the end."* I think you're confusing the first and second arg. With `0` as the first arg (with no second arg), it is sliced to the end. With `0` as the second arg, you've effectively established `0` as the number of iterations to take place when adding to the new Array being returned, and as such, an empty array is correctly returned.

Comment: @Felix: Certainly there are more important things to ponder than the minutia of ECMAScript rules, and the various browsers' inability to implement them properly. ;o)

Answer (score 5):

<strike>I'm not sure if that is defined on the standard, but I can tell you that is a tricky invocation.</strike>  Like Felix says, it's not standard behaviour, but I can think of why it's like that.

As you may know `undefined` is the value set to parameters that are not supplied when a function is called. In your example however, you are actually passing undefined, so the arguments passed are actually two and is reflected in `arguments.length`.

So from what you say happens it's easy to imagine that in Chrome, the second parameter is being checked with `typeof param2 == "undefined"`and in Firefox they use `arguments.length > 1`. So it's not (entirely) that Firefox got it wrong, like Felix suggests, they just assume `undefined` would never actually be passed in directly as the 2nd parameter.

You'll probably run into several of this cases using `undefined` like that, I'd recommend you dont use it!

Comment: Good recommendations for solid code - but the behavior is definitely standardized.

Comment: +1 Good guess about how the arguments might be handled. I don't know about the implementation, but his could be one explanation (although these methods are implemented with native code, not JavaScript).

Comment: Yeah, indeed I already fixed my code to avoid calling slice with undefined as second parameter (it was generated javascript). Nice to see anyway that the standard covers this case and that firefox in version 5 aligned its behavior.

Comment: *"So it's not (entirely) that Firefox got it wrong..."* I'd say it *is* entirely that FF got it wrong. The steps required are very specific. +1 Though since it seems very possible that they tried to take a shortcut, and ended up doing a *toInteger* conversion on `undefined` resulting in `0`.

Comment: @patrickdw: Actually a conversion to `0` would be fine, as the next step in the algorithm states: *let final be min(relativeEnd, len).* So if it would result in `0`,  the actual length of the array will be taken (that's what happens when you pass `null`). Maybe they are doing some conversion where the result is `NaN`, this gives an empty array in every browser. Try `[1,2,3].slice(1, +undefined)`.

Comment: @Felix: *"the actual length of the array will be taken"* No, that's with `0` or `null` for the *first* argument. As you pointed out *"else let final be min(relativeEnd,len)"* where *final* is the number of iterations in the *while* used in *step 10*. So if *final* is `0`, *10.a-e* are never invoked, and no items are added to the new Array created in *step 2*, and an empty Array is returned in *step 11*. This is what happens with `null` as the second argument.

Comment: @patrickdw: Oh dear... I guess I was confused by `max` in the `if` part. Of course, it's `min`...I stand correct and take everything back ;)

Answer (score 3):

The *version* of Firefox tested in the post is in the wrong here. *However, Firefox 5 works per specification* and `[1,2,3].slice(1, undefined)` evaluates to `[2,3]`.

From the [ECMAScript ed5 standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm):

> > The slice method takes two arguments, start and end, and returns a substring of the result of converting this object to a String, starting from character position start and running to, but not including, character position end  (**or  through  the  end  of  the  String  if  end  is  undefined**)...

Happy coding.